# How do I partition a rectangle into 4 parts?

Tags: python, quadtree

I'm making a program that converts a black and white image into a Quadtree, so I have to recursively divide a rectangle into 4 parts, which don't have to be equal but must stay on a whole number grid.

Something is slightly off in my logic that causes small gaps in between random squares, and I can't seem to find it.

This is the code that splits rectangles apart. It is apart of a "node" class that splits itself. Nodes take in a (x,y) tuple of the bottom left corner (stored as self.min), width, height, and then its parent.

```py
def subDivide(self):
        newHeight = math.floor(self.height/2)
        newWidth = math.floor(self.width/2)

        newHeight2 = math.ceil(self.height/2)
        newWidth2 = math.ceil(self.width/2)

        self.children.append(node(self.min, newWidth, newHeight, self))
        self.children.append(
            node((self.min[0]+newWidth2, self.min[1]), newWidth, newHeight, self))
        self.children.append(
            node((self.min[0]+newWidth2, self.min[1]+newHeight2), newWidth, newHeight, self))
        self.children.append(
            node((self.min[0], self.min[1]+newHeight2), newWidth, newHeight, self))
        return self.children
```

This is the code that renders the rectangles. The method takes in a tuple of 8 numbers (which are the x and y values of each point). My points have their y axis flipped, so I flip them back with abs(... - height) (height is the height of the entire picture).

```py
 pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, ('v2f', (x.min[0], abs(x.min[1] - height), 
                                                            x.min[0]  + x.width , abs(x.min[1] - height) ,
                                                            x.min[0]  + x.width , abs(x.min[1] + x.height - height),
                                                             x.min[0], abs(x.min[1] + x.height - height)  )), ('c3B', (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)) )
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdcds.png)
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih9R0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your subdivision function, you are making all four of your final quadrants newWidth by newHeight, but you offset the rightmost two and upper two quadrants by newWidth2 and newHeight2 pixels, respectively, so there is a one-pixel-wide gap between left/right or top/bottom halves in the cases where self has an odd-numbered length or width.

Try

```
def subDivide(self):
        newHeight = math.floor(self.height/2)
        newWidth = math.floor(self.width/2)

        newHeight2 = math.ceil(self.height/2)
        newWidth2 = math.ceil(self.width/2)

        self.children.append(node(self.min, newWidth, newHeight, self))
        self.children.append(
            node((self.min[0]+newWidth, self.min[1]), newWidth2, newHeight, self))
        self.children.append(
            node((self.min[0]+newWidth, self.min[1]+newHeight), newWidth2, newHeight2, self))
        self.children.append(
            node((self.min[0], self.min[1]+newHeight), newWidth, newHeight2, self))
        return self.children
```

Comment: Thank You! I was thinking about the pixels rather than the lines between them.